# CSS code change for underline animation starting from the center

Tags: css, animation, menu, hover, underline

I want to change the menu underline effect on hover: "from left to right" (the one I have) to "from middle and to both sides". This is the code I'm using: what should I change to do that?

```
/* Top Menu Underline animation on hover & underlined active link */  

#top-menu .current-menu-item a::before,
#top-menu .current_page_item a::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 left: 20;
 right: 0;
}
#top-menu li a:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -2;
 left: 20px;
 right: 100%;
 bottom: -8px;

 background: #474747; /*** COLOR OF THE LINE ***/
 height: 2px; /*** THICKNESS OF THE LINE ***/
 -webkit-transition-property: right;
 transition-property: right;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
 transition-duration: 0.2s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
 transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
#top-menu li a:hover {
 opacity: 1 !important;
}
#top-menu li a:hover:before {
 right: 0;
}
#top-menu li li a:before {
 bottom: 0%;
}
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```css
 body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      padding: 50px;
    }

    li {
      color: black;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 32px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    li:after {
      content: '';
      display: flex;
      border-bottom: solid 2px red;
      transform: scaleX(0);
      transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
    }

    li:hover:after {
      transform: scaleX(1);
    }
```

```html
<li>here is your link</li>
```

Comment: I need to modify very little my existing code... to get the changes. Can someone help me? thanks

Comment: Any clues? thanks

Comment: it might be a pain to get it working with your existing markup and css. If possible, it would serve you better to refactor your markup to suit the simplified css.